# New to R. I am trying add .01 the 0.00 values in the Glass$Fe from the mlbench package

Tags: r

I don't what to assign the 0.00 as NA but by simply adding .01 to all values that are 0.00.  I need this to eliminate an error using symbox from the car package.

> symbox(Glass$Fe, data=Glass, powers=c(3,2,1,0,-0.5,-1,-2))
>   Error in bc1(out, lambda) : First argument must be strictly positive.

My instructor recommended not to remove the 0.00 values just make them slightly positive.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

A more complete question would have included code to load whatever package has `symbox` as well as a sample data set, but if the only desire is to shift the values of Glass$Fe .01 toward the positive side then try:

```
symbox(Glass$Fe+0.01, data=Glass, powers=c(3,2,1,0,-0.5,-1,-2))
```